# Remove prefix from string with .split results in Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, split, substring

I have this string with a strange prefix and I've tried using the split function to return an array after the back slash character "\". This is the string: i:0#.w|itun\allepage_fg

This is what I tried:

```
function claimOrder(){
    var user = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldName: "Name",
    debug: false
    });

    var trimUser = user.split("\");

    $().SPServices.SPFindPeoplePicker({
    peoplePickerDisplayName: "NAPA User",
    valueToSet: trimUser[1],
    checkNames: true
    });
}
```

I get error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash inside a string literal:

```
var trimUser = user.split("\\");
```

In the future, when you get an error like that, it would help to tell us the relevant line. This case was obvious, but they won't all be.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I'll try to remember that for next time. But yea you're right, it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding another backslash : 
      var trimUser = user.split("\");